# Android in-app-billing not working on Wear OS, only on the phone

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, wear-os, in-app-billing

When installed directly on a phone the app works well. However, on a wearable "onPurchasesUpdated" is not called after the purchase was completed through the phone, so the purchase cannot be acknowledged.

Also "queryPurchases" always only returns an empty list, even though a purchase was made on the phone. "queryPurchaseHistory" shows the purchase, but cannot be used to acknowledge.
"onPurchasesUpdated" is only called when the process is cancelled on the wearable side.

```
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(application)
    .setListener(this).enablePendingPurchases().build();
//only called when cancelled on wearable, never when cancel/complete on phone
@Override 
public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, 
    @Nullable List<Purchase> list) {
    ...
}
```

I tried billing:5.1.0 & 4.1.0, license tester account, 2 different phones and 3 different watches.
Even Googles sample code "TrivialTestDrive" shows the same issue here.
What could I be missing?